Changing a column based on the date of another column
I have a project I'm working on, and I am running into an issue. I have a list that I created to track checklist and the customer wanted to have the status column change automatically when the due date of the checklist gets both 2 months out and when the checklist is overdue. The checklist are due every 6 months, and having to go in and update the status themselves adds unneeded stress to their work load. I have done some research and found that a power automate flow would not work for this because flow can only run for 30  days. Does anyone have any solutions to for this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Have you considered Schedule Cloud Flow, which would loop through all the checklist records in the list where (NextRenewDate-PreviousRenewedDate)> 2 months or more and then update each item with appropriate Statuses? It can be scheduled daily, weekly etc. Let me know if you need any help setting up the schedule cloud flow
